# Angular JS Routing Issue with MVC Area

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am new to Angular JS. I have a  `MVC Area` called "**Setup**". Under this area there is a `Controller` called `ModuleMstController`.

The above controller has an `Action` method **GridData**.

From my Angular controller i make a post with a url `/Setup/ModuleMst/GridData`

but firebug shows the request url as

```
http://localhost/ModuleMst/GridData
```

and my action method is not hit.

I then tried to configure routing as

```
var ap = angular.module('myApp', ['trNgGrid', 'ngRoute']);

//controller 1
ap.controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.model = {};

......
....

$scope.isAjaxInProgress = true;
$scope.errorMessage = undefined;

$http.post("/ModuleMst/GridData", $scope.requestedItemsGridOptions)
.then(function (data) {
    $scope.model.itemList = data.items;
    $scope.model.totalCount = data.TotalCount;
}
,function () {
    $scope.errorMessage = "An Error has occured while loading data!";
});

})
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/ModuleMst', {
        templateUrl: '/Setup/ModuleMst/GridData'
        //controller: 'ModuleMst',
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!');

}]);
```

I have not touched the routing configuration in the server side. It works with jquery ajax but not with angular `$http.post()`.

How do i make this work ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you show the code where you do $http.post?

Comment: @fikkatra Its in the source :) Line no 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the MVC area in the http post:

```
$http.post("/Setup/ModuleMst/GridData", $scope.requestedItemsGridOptions)
```